find a parameter a so that f(z) is analytic in the whole complex plane except at the point (0,0) where im(f(z)) = 3 + ax^2 - y^2 - y/2(x^2 + y^2)
given the imaginary part of a function im(f(z)) = 3 + ax^2 - y^2 - y/2(x^2 + y^2), is there a value for a where the function f(z) is analytic in the complex plane except possibly at the point (0,0).
is there a way to integrate this that gets a solution? or is there a rule where dosent matter the value of a the function is not analytic?
ive started by using Cauchy Reimann equations because an analytic function must satisfy the equation du/dx = dv/dy, du/dy = -dv/dx where v(x,y) = im(f(z)), u(x,y) = re(f(z)).
I got that dv/dx = 2ax + xy/(x^2 + y^2)^2
and dv/dy = -2y - (x^2 + y^2)/2(x^2 + y^2)^2
and from here im having trouble with the integration, I tried doing integral by substitution but kept getting stuck...

Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, e.g., basic help on mathjax notation, mathjax tutorial and quick reference, main meta site math tutorial and equation editing how-to.

The numerator at the end of your calculation of $\frac{\partial  v}{\partial y}$ should be $x^2\color{red}-y^2$.

You are on the right track. You calculated what $A:=-\frac{\partial  u}{\partial y}$ and $B:=\frac{\partial  u}{\partial x}$ ought to be. Now, the condition for such a function
$u$ to exist is $-\frac{\partial  A}{\partial x}=\frac{\partial  B}{\partial y}$.
